# macro to catch errors in Julia assignment

Tags: macros, julia

I seem to fall back into trial-and-error programming when working with Julia macros, and this is no exception. I'm trying to write a simple macro that catches any error in an expression and sets a flag if the expression fails. It's a macro because I want the expression (which likely includes one or more assignment statements) to be evaluated in the calling context. So, something like:

```
macro flag_errors(ex)
    broken = false
    esc(quote
        try
            $(ex)
        catch
            broken = true
        end
    end) 
end
```

I've tried various ways of nesting the `esc` function, but I have yet to find a method that properly evaluates the assignment in the call environment:

```
julia> @flag_errors a=2
2

julia> a
a not defined

julia> @flag_errors a=2+"X"
true

julia> a
a not defined

julia> broken
broken not defined
```

What's the right way to write this macro? Is the `try` block causing the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Toivo that it's a matter of scope. For example, running the following code correctly assigns a in the global environment:

```
julia>@flag_errors global a = 2
a

julia>a
2
```

So that solves the problem if you're OK with `a` existing in the global environment. We'd have to further experiment if this was already in another scope (function, try, etc.).

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things wrong here. One is that you have two unrelated variables named `broken` – one in the macro and one in the quoted body. Another is the lack of hygiene escaping of the expression – it should be interpolated as `$(esc(ex))` in order to indicate to the macro expander that it should be evaluated in the macro caller's context, not the macro definition context. And lastly there's the scope issue that Toivo mentioned. The scope analysis required to make this behave as though it weren't in a new block might not even be possible; I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `try` block is the culprit here, since it introduces a new scope block. It would take some pretty serious metaprogramming to analyze the assignments in `ex` to be able to undo this in general. Why do you need it?

Comment: I'm trying to catch errors in setup blocks for an enhancement in extras/test.jl. Ideally, errors would be caught in such a way that test suite reporting isn't broken.